# How to split the data in a group of N lines and find intersection character

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataset like below:

```
data="""vJrwpWtwJgWrhcsFMMfFFhFp
jqHRNqRjqzjGDLGLrsFMfFZSrLrFZsSL
PmmdzqPrVvPwwTWBwg
wMqvLMZHhHMvwLHjbvcjnnSBnvTQFn
ttgJtRGJQctTZtZT
CrZsJsPPZsGzwwsLwLmpwMDw"""
```

These are separate lines. Now, I want to group the data in a `set of 3 rows` and find the intersecting character in those lines. For example, `r` is the common character in the first group and `Z` is the typical character in the second group. So, below is my code:

```
lines = []
for i in range(len(data.splitlines())):
    lines.append(data[i])
    for j in lines:
        new_line = [k for k in j[i] if k in j[i + 1]]
        print(new_line)
```

It gives me a string index out-of-range error.

```
new_line = [k for k in j[i] if k in j[i + 1]]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Is this AoC day3 puzzle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record: this was the Advent of Code 2022 Day 3 Part 2 challenge. I kept my data in a file called `input.txt` and just read line by line, but this solution can be applied to a string too.

I turned converted every line into a `set` and used the `&` intersection operator. From there, I converted it to a list and removed the new line character. `s[0]` is therefore the only repeated character. Like this:

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in range(0, len(lines), 3):
        s = list(set(lines[i]) & set(lines[i + 1]) & set(lines[i + 2]))
        s.remove('\n')
        print(s[0])
```

Here's an example using your `data` string. In this case, I'd split by the new line character and no longer need to remove it from the list. I'd also extract the element from the set without converting to a list:

```
data = """vJrwpWtwJgWrhcsFMMfFFhFp
jqHRNqRjqzjGDLGLrsFMfFZSrLrFZsSL
PmmdzqPrVvPwwTWBwg
wMqvLMZHhHMvwLHjbvcjnnSBnvTQFn
ttgJtRGJQctTZtZT
CrZsJsPPZsGzwwsLwLmpwMDw"""


lines = data.split('\n')
for i in range(0, len(lines), 3):
    (ch,) = set(lines[i]) & set(lines[i + 1]) & set(lines[i + 2])
    print(ch)
```

Comment: *set* is very clever here.

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant. The second part.